# Are Data in Google App Engine always stored in order?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

If I save/store a List in Google App Engine, are data always stored in order?
Example:

```
 List<String> = {"one", "two", "three"}
```

Are they stored in order? For example, using objectify:

```
 @Entity
 class { List<String> }
```

When I load the entity, are the list in the same order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list of strings will be stored in the same order.  This should also work consistently if you move to @Embedded complex objects, as detailed here http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#@Embedded